# Remove parameter from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have URL on my localhost like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?id=8
```

I want to remove `index.php?id=` from the URL and show it like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/8
```

Or:

```
http://localhost/mysite/about
```

With some character in place of integer 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/mysite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You're misunderstanding [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite).**

You must use short URLs everywhere in your code (`mysite/8`), and let your `.htaccess` redirect these fake URLs to the real one (`mysite/index.php?id=8`).

You **can not** expect a `.htaccess` to beautify your URLs magically.

---

That being said, the `.htaccess` you're looking for is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```